# Can perforce command line mark a file as merged?

Tags: perforce

In Git, I can use add to mark a file as merged.
In SVN, I can use resolved to mark a file as merged.

But in perforce, I cannot find a command to do this job. Do anyone know if perforce has a command like this?

**Update:**
I'm trying to develop a SCC wrapper for perforce and it can merge files within its environment. But after the merge (not by perforce), how can I tell perforce that this file is already merged and remove the conflict flag?

Comment: Before I post the question, I already read the documentation of perforce command line.
My real meaning is: I'm trying to develop a SCC wrapper for perforce and it can merge files within its environment. But after the merge (not by perforce), how can I tell perforce that this file is merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must integrate one file (the source) into the other file (the target).

```
p4 integrate //depot1/mydir/myfile //depot2/mydir/myfile
```

To submit the resulting changelist, you must resolve.

1. If you don't want to change the target, resolve accepting the target (ignore source)
   file.
2. If you want to overwrite the target with the source file, resolve
   accepting the source file.
3. If you want to merge the two files, accept merged.

The command for each of these is:

1. Accept target: `p4 resolve -ay //depot2/mydir/myfile`
2. Accept source: `p4 resolve -at //depot2/mydir/myfile`
3. Accept merged: `p4 resolve -am //depot2/mydir/myfile`

Finally, submit your change:

```
p4 submit # for default changelist
p4 submit -c 12345 # submit changelist # 12345
```

(there are additional resolve options that are interactive, outlined here:  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/resolve.html#1040665

Comment: resolve command require more following actions to actually merged the file. Is there a way to simple tell perforce that this files has been merged and no more action?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to resolve with "accept target" (-ay flag).  After you resolve accepting target, diff the workspace file with the target file and they should be identical.  Once you submit the changelist, Perforce will recognize these files as merged, and the target file has not been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for 'p4 resolve -am'.

If you provide more information, that would help others give you advice.

Comment: I already try this before. And it will complain something like:
HistoryVersion.txt -
merging //user/HistoryVersion.txt#3
Diff chunks: 0 yours + 0 theirs + 0 both + 1 conflicting
//user/HistoryVersion.txt -
resolve skipped.